# 'rails s' throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications, configure

I am configuring a Rails APP. I did bundle install properly. Also using ruby 1.8.7 using RVM. Now after bundle install, it is throwing the below given error while doing rails s.

> /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:335:in `bin_path': can't find
> executable rails for rails-3.2.9 (Gem::Exception)

Can anyone help me to sort out this?

> Using ruby: 1.8.7
>
> Rails Version: 3.0.3

Comment: what would you get when u do 'gem list rails' ??

Comment: *** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (3.2.9, 3.0.3)
rails3-generators (0.17.3)
rails3-jquery-autocomplete (1.0.10, 1.0.6)

Comment: uninstall that rails 3.2.9. It may work.

Comment: No. Rails 3.2.9 is needed for another project. How we could resolve the above issue without removing rails 3.2.9?

Comment: Create different gemset for rails 3.2.9. https://rvm.io/gemsets/creating/

Comment: what is the output for `rails -v`

Comment: /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:335:in `bin_path': can't find executable rails for rails-3.2.9 (Gem::Exception)
 from /usr/bin/rails:19

Answer (score 1):

After running bundle install, your `Gemfile.lock` has a list of all the gems and their versions that are needed.

However, you need to run `bundle exec` in order for bundler to make those gem versions available to you.

The rails script is an exception, as it invokes bundler for you, but it sounds like something isn't working in your environment.

Try executing the rails script using bundle exec like so:

`bundle exec rails s`

And see if that helps.  Also, from the man who wrote bundler: http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/

Answer (score 0):

You have two rails gem versions in same gemset so it is picking latest version. So you need to specify rails version for rails commands.

Try this:

```
  $ rails _3.0.3_ server
```

Comment: No. Errors thrown:

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require': /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/acts_as_tree-1.2.0/lib/acts_as_tree.rb:65: odd number list for Hash (SyntaxError)
        foreign_key:   "parent_id",
                    ^

Comment: Yes. did that successfully

Comment: Create different gemset and try.